# jquery not working in sharepoint 2013

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

as many suggested, i did:

1. uploaded jquery-1.12.4.min.js to SiteAssets.
2. Added to a list in this site Script editor web part.
3. Added the following code to load and check if jQuery works but it doesn't and can't find the answer for hours, including many many searches in here:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://sharepoint_site/sites/firstSite/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SiteAssets/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">   
   </script> 
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
            alert('works'); 
       }); 
   </script>`
   ```

Things i tried:

1. the alert works outside of the $ mark that uses jquery
2. the url provides me to download the js file in ei, in chrome the js is 
   displayed.
3. when i copy the content of jquery and paste it above the code in the same script editor web part inside `<script></script>` ofc, the check works.
4. I'm frustrated.

Comment: your jquery reference is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your jquery reference from this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sharepoint_site/sites/firstSite/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/SiteAssets/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">
```

To this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sharepoint_site/sites/firstSite/SiteAssets/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">
```

You are using a redirection link created by a SharePoint feature called Minimal Download Strategy and thats why you see that URL in the browser, it is intended to load pages faster and some other stuff that SharePoint does, however it shouldn't be used as a file reference, when you are adding a file reference in code you need to use the real path to the file, in this case is 
http://sharepoint_site/sites/firstSite/SiteAssets/jquery-1.12.4.min.js

You can find more information about Minimal Download Strategy in the following pages:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn456544.aspx

http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013---introduction-to-the-minimal-download-strategy-mds

http://www.hezser.de/blog/2012/08/18/what-is-the-_layouts15start-aspx-in-sharepoint-2013/

http://tech.bool.se/make-javascript-code-work-with-minimal-download-strategy-part-1/

Note that those resources explain advanced topics that may not be useful for your case, proceed with caution when reading them. I have already explained all you need to know for your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

as i came today for trying, it worked me like this: [although im pretty sure ive tried it yesterday]
got in this time to shared documents, clicked at the '...' of jquery which was uploaded to there too, copied the url.
Edited the script editor web part in the list page and fixed the line like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://http://sharepoint_site/sites/firstSite/shared%20Documents/jquery-1.12.4.min.js">
```

and for some  reason, now it works!

Isaac E. Krauss, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome, but I'm wondering why you didnt select my answer as the right one, in case there is any doubt let me clarify this a little bit, you are using the same kind of URL that I was telling you to use, it doesn't matter the location of your file, is just a matter of using the correct URL or Path, the real reason of your problem is already explainded in my answer, so if you dont mind to mark my answer I would really appreciate that. I'm almost sure it was unintentionally, but in case not, please provide me some feedback so I can improve my answers in the future.